# "The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination" when uploading csv to sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv, windows-services, ssms

I am trying to upload CSV to SQL server by transforming the CSV to Datatable then this Datatable to be inserted into SQL data server. The CSV is read correctly into Datatable but while inserting the data to SQL this error occurs

> "The given Column Mapping does not match up with any column in the
>   source or destination"

Here is my code:

```
static void InsertDataIntoSQLServerUsingSQLBulkCopy(DataTable csvFileData)
    {
        System.IO.File.Create("C:\\Users\\Rana\\Desktop\\inside.txt");
        using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-N7OIK1O\\MSSQLSERVER02;Initial Catalog=nokia_Alarm;Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
        {
            System.IO.File.Create("C:\\Users\\Rana\\Desktop\\inside1.txt");
            dbConnection.Open();
            using (SqlBulkCopy s = new SqlBulkCopy(dbConnection))
            {
                System.IO.File.Create("C:\\Users\\Rana\\Desktop\\inside2.txt");
                s.DestinationTableName = "csv_Table";

                foreach (var column in csvFileData.Columns)
                    s.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ToString(), column.ToString());
                s.WriteToServer(csvFileData);
                System.IO.File.Create("C:\\Users\\Rana\\Desktop\\inside4.txt");
            }
        }
    }
```

I do not know where the problem is ?

is it in the DB connection ?

> (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection("Data
>   Source=DESKTOP-N7OIK1O\MSSQLSERVER02;Initial
>   Catalog=nokia_Alarm;Integrated Security=SSPI)

Comment: Make sure all of the columns in table `nokia_Alarm.dbo.csv' exist in the `DataTable` and visa-versa.

Comment: yes , i checked and they are all in the table

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
foreach (DataColumn column in csvFileData.Columns)
                    s.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ColumnName, column.ColumnName);
```

DataTables and most of the ADO.NET types predate generic collections, so when `foreach`-ing its collections (like DataTable.Columns) you have to provide target type in the `foreach` to access its properties and methods.

Comment: Then update your question with the table DDL and a list of the DataTable Columns, perhaps by including the output of DataTable.WriteXmlSchema https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.writexmlschema?view=netframework-4.7.2